# how to implement facet search api on content types feilds?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, search

Is it necessary to build taxonomy for each field of content type to show it in search option in sidebar in facet search api ?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps here and you will be done. https://beautiful7mind.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/step-by-step-how-to-implement-facet-search-on-data-in-drupal-7/